# Suggested ways of identifying hardware on Ubuntu

Tags: hardware, modprobe, lspci

I am getting asked a lot if a certain hardware is supported on Ubuntu (or Linux for that matter). Usually people tell me the brand and model of their alledgedly unsupported hardware, but of course not the chipsets that are in these models. What should I tell them to identify the USB or PCIe device?

My current approach is like this

- [Probe your computer on linux-hardware.org](https://linux-hardware.org/) with the [Ubuntu Hardware_probe package](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hardware_probe)
- Use the [Ubuntu discover package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/discover) or lspci, lsusb to find Vendor and Device ID
- [Check if your device is listed in the parts search of Hardware for Linux](https://linux-hardware.org/?view=search)

Any refined, better or easier (beginner friendly) methods? People are usually overwhelmed by the device and vendor IDs.

Comment: Respond with "I don't know,  try it", hand them a current Ubuntu install. USB, along with instructions to boot into "Try Ubuntu" mode. Then look at system hardware detection with `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`